# If you cast a spell with a focus component and a long duration, does it end if the focus component goes missing?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, spell-components, spellcasting-focus, duration

I can't seem to find a good example outside of 3rd party materials right now and pending GM or Dev input I figured I'd ask here.  The example I'm specifically looking at is the Dart Gun I spell from Ponyfinder with a 24 hour duration that uses a focus component that is an armlet worth at least 25g.  If that armlet were removed for some reason (stolen, confiscated, handed to someone else, etc) would the spell duration end at that point or is the focus component only needed for the initial casting?  If it were a Concentration spell I could see it needing to stick around, but IDK otherwise.  Anyone have any official rulings on this?

Comment: So you know, while this question's fine as-is, better answers are usually received when the question asks about the specific case then lets the respondents generalize if they want. (Often answers will strive for completeness by addressing *both* the specific case *and* the general case.) I mean, currently, folks looking for information *on the same spell* won't find this question by searching for the spell!

Comment: I am always hesitant to mention the spell and its source because of obvious reasons considering the source in question.  I have edited those in now though.

Comment: I'm not judging. We're all in this hobby together, man. Now, which *Ponyfinder* product includes the *dart gun I* spell?

Comment: Kollective 23 - The Living Factory

Answer (score 2):

## Losing a spell's divine or arcane focus component after casting the spell typically has no ill effects on the spell

Unless the spell says otherwise, a spell's components only need to be satisfied during the spell's casting: On [Components](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#Components) says, "A spell’s components explain what you must do or possess to cast the spell," and among those components is a focus component. Later, [Casting Time](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#Casting_Time) details when a spell comes into effect, ending its casting, and no longer mandating the spell's caster satisfy the spell's components.

Thus in the same way that a spell must say that it requires the caster to gesture continually throughout its duration or else the spell's duration ends (none to my knowledge do, by the way), a spell must also say that any focus component is required throughout the spell's duration *and* explain the consequences of its loss.

For example, the [*shapechange*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/shapechange/) spell has as its focus component a jade circlet with a price of 1,500 gp, but after casting the spell the caster can do whatever with that circlet without worrying about the spell ending prematurely or any other effects. (Using the *shapechange* spell to change form may cause the circlet to meld with the caster—see [Transmutation](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#Transmutation) on Polymorph—, but casting the spell then doffing the circlet then taking a free action to change form using the spell's effect is totally legit.) Compare this to the consequences described for destroying the focus of the [*magic jar*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/magic-jar/) spell while the caster's life force is inside the focus.

Comment: I feel like there are some spells that you need the Focus or Material component to like... aim the spell... For example, Scrying. I feel like their are others, but none come to mind quickly.

Comment: @Ifusaso The [*scrying*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/scrying/) spell's weird. While it's easy to imagine the caster viewing the subject's actions in that snazzy 1,000-gp silver mirror (or free puddle), the spell doesn't actually say that's what happens. Technically, the mirror (or puddle) is just for show, maybe with the caster getting a PiP view of the subject that doesn't interfere with the caster's normal sight? GM's call, really, but, as written, the components? They do nothing. The spell's effect is all in the caster's head.

Comment: @Ifusaso (It's the actual, explicit physical effect that makes the spell [*blood biography*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/blood-biography/) so awesome, by the way. The results of that spell very difficult to forge, but Mr. Yrcs can say that, for example, his *scrying* spell that he's using right now proves Rellik is the murderer and only *more magic* will prove that he's telling the truth and that he wasn't instead just using the spell to violate a random dude's privacy or even that the subject succeeded on the saving throw.)